# How to get rid of the segmentation error while using C

Tags: c, initialization, printf, c-strings

[Segmentation error in stdio.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aISdp.png)

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main()
{
    char arr[4]={"abcd"};
    char *p;
    p=arr;

    for(int i;i<4;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",p[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i dont know why it is showing as segmentation error in my stdio.h file while im just doing a simple code............................................................................

Comment: do not spam tags. How is it related to c#

Comment: Your image shows that you made a wrong ```printf``` formatting. ```%s``` is for null-terminated strings while inside your look you would want to print out a ```character```. Instead use ```printf("%c\n", p[i]);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You invoke uncountable numbers of UBs in this short program.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void)
{
    char arr[5]="abcd";   // string also includes null character terminator.
    char *p;
    p=arr;

    printf("%s\n", p);  // you need to pass pointer to null terminated char array (C string) to use %s format

//             v-- you need to initialize it 
    for(size_t i = 0;i < strlen(p);i++)
    {
        printf("%c\n",p[i]); // you want to print char not string
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate you for doing this.
I'm altogether new to C and stuff; all I knew until now was Python that's why I spam-tagged C# and C++. I'm really sorry about that

Comment: Note `arr[5]` is only needed if you are planning on using it as a null terminated string. It's not needed when used as in the original code.

Comment: @TedLyngmo If the intention is to not use null termination, then using a string literal for initialization is always bad practice. `char arr[4]={'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};` should be used in that case.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, I personally agree that that would be clearer. OP did however not make the mistake of trying to use it as a string so changing `arr[4]` to `arr[5]` does nothing to _"get rid of the segmentation error"_ in OPs code, as was asked for.

Answer (score 4):

There are two mistakes:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { // i must be initialized
    printf("%c\n", p[i]);     // use %c instead of %s
}
```

- When leaving `i` uninitialized it has an indeterminate value and reading from it makes the program have undefined behavior.
- Using `%s` (which expects a `const char*`) when you supply an `int` also has undefined behavior. `%c` is for printing a single character.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 

/* Another common way in C to iterate to a string char by char.
 * The prameter s must be a null-terminated string since
 * the while condition exploits that '\0' == 0. Note that 0 is treated as false. */
void my_string_print(char *s) {
  while(*s)  printf("%c\n",*(s++)); 
}


int main() {
 // Array notation is not needed, since the string will not be manipulated.
  char *p = "abcd";

  /* It is a good practice to use size_t when dealing with the length of a string.
   * Note that strlen requires a null-terminated string as an argument. */
    for(size_t i=0; i < strlen(p); i++) printf("%c\n",p[i]);

    puts("");  // Print an empty line for separation.
  
    my_string_print(p); // Call the custom function to print each character of the string.

    /* In the main() function, omitting 'return' is treated as successful
     * execution (exit code 0); at least in modern C (C99 and later). */
}
```

You can use the compiler flags -ggdb3 and -fsanitize=address to get an
idea of why your program is experiencing segfaults. Additionally, it's
always a good practice to enable all warnings and treat them as
errors.

Here is the content of a Makefile to build your program, assuming that it is named abcd.c.

```
CFLAGS += -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -ggdb3 -fsanitize=address

all: abcd

clean:
        $(RM) abcd
```